# Jooby custom interceptor

Tags: java, rest

**I have the following problem:**

I have a rest API on a jooby server. I want to create a custom annotation interceptor which handles particular requests and validates the oauth token in the header.

```
@GET
@Path("current")
@AuthenticationTokenValidator
public Result getCurrentUser(final Request req) {
    ...
```

Or for an entire controller

```
@Path("/v1/some_route")
@Consumes("json")
@Produces("json")
@AuthenticationTokenValidator
public class SomeController {
```

How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `filter` and then ask for route `attributes`. Something similar to this:

```
{
    use("*", (req, rsp, chain) -> {
        String value = req.route().attr("authenticationTokenValidator");
        // your code goes here
    });
}
```

Not sure if the `annotation` at the class level is supported.

Checkout the [documentation](http://jooby.org/doc/#routes-properties) about route attributes, there is a similar example.